# JQGRID (open source) Example Code MYSQL and EDIT and ADD ROW

Tags: jqgrid

I am searching a simple Example Code for Jquery Grid (Jqgrid; http://www.trirand.com/blog ) with mysql database fetching through json and using the options "add row/entry" and "edit".

Out of the code you provide i can adapt to build my own. Any contribution will be much appreciated !

Thanks for your time

Regards,
Emil

Answer (score 0):

try this tutorial:
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid